# Display data from db on HTML using Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to get a webpage to display data from my database and display it on a html page in a table and be able to scroll down on the table by rendering it in ejs. I based my code from this site https://www.tutsmake.com/node-js-fetch-and-display-data-from-mysql-database-in-html-list/

i'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, the db is connecting just fine, and I have the ejs file in my views folder. I'm guessing the issue is coming from the ejs file but I'm not sure. I've just started coding again so this is basically all new to me.

when I go to localhost:3000/test I'm getting a 404 error and when I look at the terminal it says  GET/TEST 404 20.377ms -1153, I think I might be pulling to much data at once since the there are 75 rows for this, I've tried to limit the amount of rows but it still wont load the page and for some reason this code can't even find my ejs file.

From what I've read online there are a million different ways to do this and I don't know where to start to get this working. I'm using mssql as my database and using visual studio to build everything.

this is my server.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");
var connection = require('./lib/db');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
   secret: '123456cat',
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: true,
   cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}))

app.use(flash());
app.use(expressValidator());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/index', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
   // set locals, only providing error in development
   res.locals.message = err.message;
   res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
   // render the error page
   res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error');
});
module.exports = app;
```

this is my dbaCon.js

```
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");

var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    server: 'DESKTOP-BA7Q2HM',
    port: 1433,
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    database: "tempdb",
    domain: 'DNAME',
    requestTimeout: 3600000,
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true,
        enableArtithAbort: true
    },
    debug: true,
    parseJSON: true
});

conn.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Database is connected successfully!');
});
module.exports = conn;
```

this is my users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection = require('../dbaCon.js');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    connection.query('SELECT id, status, type, Date, Review * FROM [dba].[table] ', function (err, rows) {

        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err);
            res.render('index', { page_title: "test - Node.js", data: '' });
        } else {

            res.render('index', { page_title: "test - Node.js", data: rows });
        }

    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is my index.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Display Active Loan info to Client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% if (messages.error) { %>
    <p style="color:red"><%- messages.error %></p>
    <% } %>
    <% if (messages.success) { %>
    <p class="alert alert-success mt-4"><%- messages.success %></p>
    <% } %>
    <br>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">id</th>
                <th scope="col">status</th>
                <th scope="col">type</th>
                <th scope="col">date</th>
                <th scope="col">review</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% if(data.length){
            for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {%>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><%= (i+1) %></th>
                <td><%= data[i].id%></td>
                <td><%= data[i].status%></td>
                <td><%= data[i].type%></td>
                <td><%= data[i].date%></td>
                <td><%= data[i].review%></td>
            </tr>
            <% }
            }else{ %>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">No Data Availed</td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*I think I might be pulling to much data at once since the there are 75 rows for this*" Can you elaborate on how you reached the conclusion that 75 rows is "*a lot*" in any modern computing context, or how a `404 Not Found` HTTP response code equates to trying to push too much data to the client...? Can you point explicitly to a part of any code you've provided that defines the `/test` route which you're trying to request? It's not immediately apparent that you've defined it at all to begin with, and unclear how you *wouldn't* get a 404 when requesting a nonexistent/undefined route.

Comment: Your SQL Query is incorrect. I'd fix that.

Answer (score 1):

you do not have a route for "/test".

you have these routes that points to '/WHAT_YOU_HAVE_ON_indexRouter' and '/index/WHAT_YOU_HAVE_ON_userRouter'

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/index', usersRouter);

on your userRouter you dont have a '/test' route, you need to add it.

you reach the 404 because the app cant find any route related to '/test'

Comment: so how would I make a route to my ejs file. in my post I meant to put localhost/index not 'test' so that was my mistake. but I think this code is trying to pull the index.js file from the routes not the index.ejs in the views folder. so do I need to add my index.ejs file into the routes folder? or make a route to my index.ejs in views folder. Based on the site that I based this code on the ejs file needs to be the views folder. this is all new to me so talk to me like I'm 5

Comment: First inside the route user.js you need to create the route you want to use 
router.get('/MY_ROUTE', function (req, res, next)
You can use the one created as a template, after that you need to render the correct view/page you want to use
res.render('MY_PAGE', { page_title: "test - Node.js", data: '' });
this page needs to be inside the views folder and if is inside anothe folder you need to add it as well
res.render('MY_FOLDER/MY_PAGE', { page_title: "test - Node.js", data: '' });

Comment: also in this section you are pre appending a route to you current route
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/index', usersRouter);

all routes on the indexRouter can have just a simple '/' like 'localhost/' but for userRouter all routes need to have '/index/ like 'localhost/index/'

Answer (score 0):

> when I go to localhost:3000/test I'm getting a 404 error

You didn't setup any route with the endpoint `/test`, at least not on the code you posted, that's why you get an 404 not found error.

> I think I might be pulling to much data at once since the there are 75 rows for this

No, 75 rows are no close to much data. You should edit your question to clarify each problem.